# How to create new column using loop with condition

Tags: python, loops, series

This is my DataFrame and I want to create a new column using loop with conditions.

```
import pandas as pd
student_card = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[20190103, 20190222, 20190531],
                             'name':['Kim', 'Yang', 'Park'],
                             'class':['H', 'W', 'S']})


student_card['new'] = pd.Series() #1.create new column
for i, v in student_card['name'].items(): #2.set index and values
    if "Yang" in v: #3.if there's "Yang" in value
        student_card['new'].append(v) #4. append the value of name column in new column
```

So I tried this method and got stuck with following error:

> TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid

Which is not true btw (type of this column is Series)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What `append` does is to concatenate a series, which is not the case in your code as `v` is a string, `i` is the index of that string. You can try printing `print(type(v))` and see for yourself. As for the documentation, you can find it here:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.append.html

What you are looking for is to set a value to a prexisting index on a column (or Series as its called in pandas). Something like that:

```
df.loc[index] = value
```

So in your code, this should do the trick

```
import pandas as pd
student_card = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[20190103, 20190222, 20190531],
                             'name':['Kim', 'Yang', 'Park'],
                             'class':['H', 'W', 'S']})


student_card['new'] = pd.Series() #1.create new column
for i, v in student_card['name'].items(): #2.set index and values
    if "Yang" in v: #3.if there's "Yang" in value
        student_card['new'].loc[i] = v #4. append the value of name column in new column
```

Answer (score 0):

[Append](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) will concatenate two Series. What you want is accesing a row. Use [indexing like iloc or iat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html) to do so:

```py
import pandas as pd
student_card = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[20190103, 20190222, 20190531],
                             'name':['Kim', 'Yang', 'Park'],
                             'class':['H', 'W', 'S']})


student_card['new'] = pd.Series() #1.create new column
for i, v in student_card['name'].items(): #2.set index and values
    if "Yang" in v: #3.if there's "Yang" in value
        student_card['new'].iat[i] = v #4. append the value of name column in new column
```

Output:

| (Index) | ID | name | class | new |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 20190103 | Kim | H | NaN |
| 1 | 20190222 | Yang | W | Yang |
| 2 | 20190531 | Park | S | NaN |

Answer (score 0):

You should really not use a loop to manipulate a pandas dataframe, this is an anti-pattern.

Also, `append` is now deprecated.

Use a vectorial approach with [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
# select the rows for which name==Yang and add the same name in the new column
student_card.loc[student_card['name'].eq('Yang'), 'new'] = student_card['name']
```

Or, using [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
# mask all non matching values (name!=Yang) and copy the column
student_card['new'] = student_card['name'].where(student_card['name'].eq('Yang'))
```

output:

```
         ID  name class   new
0  20190103   Kim     H   NaN
1  20190222  Yang     W  Yang
2  20190531  Park     S   NaN
```