# How to create new column using loop with condition and assign value

Tags: python, dataframe, sorting, for-loop

My question is how to assign value of 1 in my new column for each element in my unique list that will be found in the column 'ID' in my dataframe. I want to do this with for loop only.

My unique_list is being transformed into string first.

```
string_mb = ' '.join([str(item) for item in unique_list])

 df_dep_4['MB'] = pd.Series()

 for i, v in df_dep_4['ID_FINAL'].items():

     if string_mb in v:

         df_dep_4['MB'].loc[i] = v
```

I have tried like it is shown here, but couldn't relate [How to create new column using loop with condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73824180/how-to-create-new-column-using-loop-with-condition)

Answer (score 0):

Try using apply - it's roughly the same thing as the loop (inside it will loop on your rows, but inside pandas instead of explicitly outside)

```
string_mb = ' '.join([str(item) for item in unique_list])
df_dep_4['MB'] = df_dep_4['ID_FINAL'].apply(lambda x: 1 if string_mb in x else 0)
```

See this sample for how it works:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(index=['id', 'ID_FINAL'],
                  data=[
                      ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
                      ['john', 'james', 'joe', 'jack']
                  ]).T
df['MB'] = df['ID_FINAL'].apply(lambda x: 1 if 'jo' in x else 0)
print(df)
```

Results in:

```
  id ID_FINAL  MB
0  a     john   1
1  b    james   0
2  c      joe   1
3  d     jack   0
```

Comment: I got an error that there is unexpected keyword argument 'axis'. I also removed the axis, but the answer didn't assign 1.

Comment: axis was my bad - it's only a parameter when calling "apply" on a dataframe (not a series as we are here)

for why it's not assigning 1 - is it possible that you want to check if the ID_FINAL value (x in my code) is in string_mb as opposed to the other way around?

Comment: I want to check whether string_mb is in ID_FINAL, and to each row assign 1 if it finds it.

Comment: Ok - check the sample.